# Fast way to compress binary data?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have some binary data (pixel values) in a int[] (or a byte[] if you prefer) that I want to write to disk in an Android app. I only want to use a small amount of processing time but want as much compression as I can for this. What are my options?

In many cases the array will contain lots of consecutive zeros so something simple and fast like RLE compression would probably work well. I can't see any Android API functions for this though. If I have to loop over the array in Java, this will be very slow as there is no JIT on most Android devices. I could use the NDK but I'd rather avoid this if I can.

Comment: The Real question is what is the trade off. In general, I think it would be faster to write the raw bytes, as anything else is going to use processor time, such as DeflaterOutputStream or GZipOutputStream, and especially for large amounts of data may take just too long.

Comment: I imagine the overhead of RLE would be very low but I can't find an API function that will do RLE for me. Doing this in Java code on a non-JIT Android phone will be very slow. Deflater and GZip seem to use much more complex compression (i.e. Huffman) and that's going to be much slower to process.

Comment: pixel values in a int[] as in *"ARGB on 32 bits"* for each pixel where there are a lot of similar consecutive colors (which seems to be your case) can be encoded very efficiently using the lossless PNG format (I take it you want lossless).  The algorithm behing PNG used for lossless compression is called DEFLATE (basically Huffman + LZ77 according to wiki).  Dunno how powerful Android devices are but encoding a tiny (PNG screen size are really tiny compared to my 1920x1200 desktop) picture using PNG really ain't close to number crunching...

Comment: @Webinator: Encoding a 480x854 screen sized .png file take about 1 - 2 seconds on a Droid. It's slow enough to annoy the user for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeflatorOutputStream takes ~25 ms to compress 1 MB in Java. Its a native method so a JIT should not make much difference.

Do you have a requirement which says 0.2s or 0.5s is too slow?

Can you do it in a background thread so the user doesn't notice how long it takes?

GZIP is based on the Deflator + CRC32 so is likely to be much the same or slightly slower.

Deflator has several modes.  The DEFAULT_STRATEGY is fastest in Java, but simpler compressions such as HUFFMAN_ONLY might be faster for you.

Answer (score 2):

Android has Java's [DeflaterOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html). Would that work?

Comment: I can confirm it's very slow in Android. It takes about 0.5s to write a 1Mb array with deflater and it takes about 0.01s as just raw bytes!

Comment: Maybe `GZipOutputStream` would give better compression?

Comment: GZip is also pretty slow. I'm looking at about 0.2s max (20 times slower than raw saving). I've got quite a lot of disk space but I don't want to waste it if I don't have to i.e. if I had a cheap way to compress the data reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the byte array to
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

 and chain
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html
to it

then when you need to read the data back in do the reverse
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html
and chain 
 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html

Depending on the size of the file your saving you will see some compression Gzip is good like that, if your not seeing much of a trade of just write the data uncompressed using a buffered writer(That should be the fastest). Also if you do gzip it using a buffered writer reader could also speed it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to solve basically the same problem on another platform and my solution was to use a modified LZW compression.  First, do some difference filtering (similar to PNG) on the 32bpp image.  This will turn most of the image to black if there are large areas of common color. Then use a generic GIF compression algorithm treating the filtered image as if it's 8bpp.  You'll get decent compression and it works very quickly.  This will need to run in native code (NDK).  It's really quite easy to get native code working on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Random thought: if it's image data, try saving it as png. Standard java has it, i'm sure android will too, and probably optimized with native code. It has pretty good compression and it's lossless.

Comment: I've tried this and it's very slow. About x10 slower at least than just saving the raw bytes.

Comment: @RichardNewton: yup after commenting I realized DEFLATE had already been suggested.  tulskiy: PNG is using DEFLATE so no miracle here if DEFLATE is too slow for the OP.